# Why the Placement of Pour Out Thy Wrath?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

The paragraph "Pour Out Your Wrath" is in the Haggada after birchat hamazon and before Hallel.

Why might it have been placed there?

Comment: It corresponds to the stage of redemption after the “meal” has been completed. It is a consequence of our completion of the avodah of birurim/refinements. It is what is mentioned in Zechariah 13:2. And after its completion, Israel together with the whole world will offer praise to G-d.

Comment: Probably because that's when people open the door